# Intel Fortran value attribute

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

My apologies if this is a very stupid question; my Fortran isn't great.  I'm porting some old Fortran code and have come across this subroutine definition:

```
SUBROUTINE SET_HYDROMODULE(HYDROMODULE)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER*4 HYDROMODULE [VALUE]
...
END
```

Intel Fortran passes this through without blinking an eye, though with warnings for non-standard language features enabled it gives this warning:

```
warning #7009: Attribute syntax is not standard F95
```

gfortran assumes that it's an attempt at a coarray specification, though it's not a valid one.

Can someone tell me what the meaning of the `[VALUE]` clause is?

**Edit** Is it a non-standard way of specifying pass-by-value?  Is it equivalent to this:

```
INTEGER*4, VALUE :: HYDROMODULE
```

I seem to see it a lot in c-interoperability code, which would suggest this.

Comment: I think, but my memory is so dusty I'm not sure I can correctly frame an answer myself, that `[VALUE]` is a hangover from DEC Fortran, one of the ancestors of Intel Fortran, and one which implemented many extensions to the standard FORTRAN (or Fortran) of its day.  I'm not sure that it means exactly the same as the Fortran 2003 standard `VALUE` attribute.  I'm not sure it doesn't either.  Someone ought to search the Internet for an explanation.  Or hang around and wait for Steve Lionel to wake up and contribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VALUE` attribute was added in Fortran 2003, so it is not surprising that it doesn't work with Fortran 95. The Fortran Standard (2008) specifies in section 5.3.18 "VALUE attribute". From what I read there, it needs to be specified as

```
INTEGER*4, VALUE :: HYDROMODULE
```

Section 5.4.16 in the Standard defines a second form, the `VALUE` statement:

```
INTEGER*4 :: HYDROMODULE
VALUE     :: HYDROMODULE
```

The other form you gave seems to be an Intel extension. gfortran [supports the `VALUE` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gfortran/Interoperable-Subroutines-and-Functions.html) (at least in version 4.9).

A quick search revealed that apart from ensuring [inter-operability](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gfortran/Interoperable-Subroutines-and-Functions.html) the `VALUE` attribute can indeed by used to enforce some kind of call by value, from [here](http://labcalc.fisica.uniroma1.it/home/fortran/doc/main_for/mergedProjects/lref_for/source_files/attribute_value.htm):

> When this attribute is specified, the effect is as if the actual
>   argument is assigned to a temporary, and the temporary is the argument
>   associated with the dummy argument. The actual mechanism by which this
>   happens is determined by the processor.

Comment: But there is a very important difference between your last "side-note" approach and a dummy argument with the VALUE argument - an actual argument that is an expression must not be modified by the procedure, while a VALUE dummy argument can.  Given the use cases for VALUE in Fortran, this difference is material.

Comment: @IanH that's true - it's the reason why I only added it as a side-note. It's a simplification that *might* be applicable.

Comment: It also doesn't change the calling convention!

Comment: OK... I removed the side-note.